# Fundamental group of simply connected 4-manifold minus a connected surface

Tags: manifolds, fundamental-groups

If $X$ is a simply connected 4-manifold and $\Sigma\subset X$ is a connected and oriented surface, then can we say anything about the index 2 subgroups of $\pi_1(X\setminus\Sigma)$?

(Best case for me would be to say that there are no index 2 subgroups. I'm pretty sure that's false though since Alexander duality implies that $H_1(S^4\setminus\Sigma)=H^2(\Sigma)=\mathbb Z$. So $\pi_1(S^4\setminus\Sigma)$ is nontrivial and probably is at least sometimes $\mathbb Z$, which obviously has an index 2 subgroup.)

Comment: In general, there is a bijection between index $2$ subgroups of $\pi_1(X)$ and $H^1(X;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$.  If $H\subseteq \pi_1$ is index $2$, we get a map $f:\pi_1\rightarrow \pi_1/H\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  Since the target is abelian, this map factors through $H_1$, we we obtain a map $\hat{f}:H_1(X;\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, that is, an element of $Hom(H_1(X);\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  Since $H^0$ is free, we can identify $Hom(X;G)$ with $H^1(X;G)$ via the universal coefficient theorem.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I guess that's probably as good of a general statement as can be made—makes sense though, since it would be incredibly strong to be able to limit $\pi_1(X\setminus\Sigma)$ in the way I was hoping to.